# does proxychains redirect all traffic of any application?

Tags: proxy, bind, port, proxychains, socks5-proxy

From [linuxbabe.com](https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/how-to-use-proxychains-to-redirect-your-traffic-through-proxy-server#comment-30525):

```
proxychains bash
```

> This command will start another bash shell with proxychains in your terminal and from now on you don’t have to prepend proxychains to your command. Your traffic in this new shell will be automatically redirected through proxy server.

So when I use for example:

```
proxychains google-chrome
```

I expect that all the traffic of my browser will be redirected through my proxychains proxy but this doesn't happen.
Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that it's because I had another chrome window open. If

```
proxychains google-chrome
```

Is the first window of chrome browser you are opening it will work.
I don't know why but I think google chrome just can use one way of connecting to internet and you can't have two windows of chrome and each one has it's own proxy.